# MySQL filter on column value within multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have these two tables:

```
|Customers     |          |Purchases      |
----------------          -----------------
|CusID         |-----     |PurchaseID     |
|CusName       |     |---<|CusID          |
|CusAge        |          |ItemName       |
|CusDateAdded  |          |DatePurchased  |
```

I am needing to filter my result set by multiple ItemNames. Say I want to return all Customers who are between the ages of 18 and 24 who purchased a 'camera' AND a 'phone'. I can run the following query to obtain all records for customers between the age range:

```
SELECT CusID
FROM Customers AS C
JOIN Purchases AS P
ON C.CusID = P.CusID
WHERE C.CusAge BETWEEN 18 AND 24
```

However when it comes time to filter on the ItemName column in Purchases table how does one filter on multiple rows? Supposing it is possible without multiple queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT C.CusID
FROM Customers AS C
JOIN Purchases AS P ON C.CusID = P.CusID
WHERE C.CusAge BETWEEN 18 AND 24
AND ItemName IN ('camera','phone')
GROUP BY C.CusID
HAVING count(distinct ItemName) = 2
```

Group by the customer and return only those having both items.

Comment: I might be looking at this wrong, please correct me if I am, but what if the Customer had more purchases than just 'camera' and 'phone'. Say they also purchased a 'shirt' and 'hat' which would make their total record in Purchases table equal to 4. Since I only care about 'camera' and 'phone', when I run the HAVING count(distinct ItemName) = 2, would this overlook a customer that had purchased a camera and a phone plus other items?

Comment: But in your `where` clause you only look at `AND ItemName IN ('camera','phone')`. So it does not matter if there are others

Comment: You are most certainly correct. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will answer your question: **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcd06/11)**

```
SELECT C.CustID,C.CustName,P.ItemName
FROM Customers AS C
JOIN Purchases AS P ON C.CustID = P.CustID
GROUP BY C.CustID,C.CustName,P.ItemName
HAVING P.ItemName IN ('camera','phone')
```

Comment: When a record is added to purchases table for Cust3 with ItemName = 'phone', then Cust3 also shows up in the results even though they had not purchased 'camera'